# Homework Question related to Poisson Kernel

Tags: real-analysis

The following is a question from my homework:

Let $a_n$, $b_n$ be the Fourier coefficient of a $2\pi$-periodic, integrable function $f$ on $[-\pi$,$\pi$]. ($a_n$ is the Fourier coefficient of $cos(nx)$ and $b_n$ is is the Fourier coefficient of $sin(nx)$)

I have shown that the series

$$a_0+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}r^n(a_ncos(nx)+bnsin(nx))$$
converges uniformly to 
$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} P_r(z)f(x+z)\,dz$, where $P_r(z)=\frac{1-r^2}{1-2rcosz+r^2}$ (The Poisson Kernel).

Let this function be $f_r$.
The question asks me to prove the following statement.

- If $f$ is continuous at some $x$ in $[-\pi$,$\pi$], then then $\lim_{r\to 1} f_r(x)$=$f(x)$.

My attempt:

Apply the equality

$$a_0+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}r^n(a_ncos(nx)+bnsin(nx))=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} P_r(z)f(x+z)\,dz$$
on the function $h(x)=1$.
Then we get

$$1=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} P_r(z)\,dz$$
Thus

$$|f_r(z)-f(z)|=|\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} P_r(z)(f(x+z)-f(x))\,dz|$$
I find out that $\lim_{r\to 1}P_r(0)={\infty}$. So I decide to split the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$ into two parts, the first part is from $-h$ to $h$ for some small $h>0$ and the second part is $[-\pi,\pi]\setminus[-h,h]$ to approximate the integral.

However, I have trouble in considering the integral from $0$ to $h$ because $P_r(0)$ diverges as r approaches $1$.

Any suggestion to do this problem?

Answer (score 0):

To be edited.
$\lim_{x\to0}P_r(x)$ diverges does not mean that $P_r(x)$ is not improper integrable.

The question requires to prove the following:

- If $f$ is continuous at some $x$ in $[-\pi,\pi]$, then $\lim_{r\to 1}f_r(x)=f(x)$, where $f_r(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi P_r(z)f(x+z)dz$, and $P_r(z)$ is the Poisson kernel.

The statement follows directly from the following two lemmas.

- **Lemma I**
  For any sequence $a_n\in[0,1)$ such that $\lim a_n=1$, $P_{a_n}$ is a family of good kernels.
- **Lemma II**
  Let $\big\{K_n(x)\big\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be a family of good kernels, and $f$ be an integrable $2\pi$-periodic function. Then$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(f*K_n)(x)=f(x)$$
  whenever $f$ is continuous at $x$.
  The definition of *good kernel* and proof of **Lemma II** can be found in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1392772/good-kernels-properties).
  You may check out [this link](http://math.uchicago.edu/~may/REU2012/REUPapers/Cuddy.pdf), which provides proof of the problem.
  Have fun with Prof. Chau!

Comment: while the link might contain the solution, just a suggestion to try to summarize the main idea or concept to improve quality of the post.

Comment: Thanks, I will do it after class. Just too surprised to catch a classmate here.